# Mysql insert with IF condition is it possible?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with only 3 columns (id - primary key / status / timestamp). Periodically I receive a status message which can be 0 or 1 and I need to insert it in that table but only if the last status inserted is different.
Is there any way to do this is only one mysql query ?

Basically I need to do this :

```
SELECT status FROM `status_e_distr_c01` order by id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Then compare my status message with select result and if is different then do insert, if not...do nothing...

So how can I do this in one mysql query ?
Thank you very much

Comment: Do you want to insert or update? why do you want to insert only if the status is different?

Comment: I am using this in a nodered automation, and get status every minute so i don t want to fill in the table with all values. Basically if I insert only when is different then I know when was changed. I don t want update because i need a history....

Comment: do you receive status related to a id (which is a primary key)? Or the primary key is auto-incremented?

Comment: id is just auto-incremented ,status is not related to id..

Comment: Please share more details - the question asks about an `INSERT`, while your only attempt is a `SELECT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO status_e_distr_c01 (status)
SELECT @new_status
FROM ( SELECT status
       FROM status_e_distr_c01
       ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 1 ) subquery
WHERE subquery.status != @new_status;
```

PS. Will fail if destination table is empty. The most first row must be inserted without thes checking.

---

**UPDATE**

```sql
INSERT INTO status_e_distr_c01 (status)
SELECT @new_status
WHERE @new_status != COALESCE(( SELECT status
                                FROM status_e_distr_c01
                                ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 1 ), 2);
```

Works on empty table too.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=205621ef271a9f19b1a1691ff72e27b4)

---

The same as stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_if_changed (IN new_status INT)
INSERT INTO status_e_distr_c01 (status)
SELECT new_status
WHERE new_status != COALESCE(( SELECT status
                               FROM status_e_distr_c01
                               ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 1 ), 2);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb0604b82e8024c10d9574f3d1912c0e)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the values of the columns that you want to insert are `:status`, `:timestamp` you can do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO status_e_distr_c01 (status, timestamp)
SELECT :status, :timestamp
FROM dual
WHERE :status <> 
      COALESCE((SELECT status FROM status_e_distr_c01 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1), NOT :status)
```

The code will work even if the table is empty.
You may omit `FROM dual` if your version of MySql is 5.7+.
See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=06a180f986be29c208825952612de9d3).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM` the `dual` pseudo table and check if the target table is empty or the new status differs from the last one selected in a subquery.

```
INSERT INTO status_e_distr_c01
            (status)
            SELECT ?
                   FROM dual
                   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                            FROM status_e_distr_c01)
                          OR ? <> (SELECT status
                                          FROM status_e_distr_c01
                                          ORDER BY id DESC
                                          LIMIT 1);
```